# Code accessing continuous L1 cache memory slower than code accessing 3x non-continuous L1 memory

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, assembly, x86

This question is an update to this: [Accessing three static arrays is quicker than one static array containing 3x data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162398/accessing-three-static-arrays-is-quicker-than-one-static-array-containing-3x-dat) but I have too many updates so it made sense to start a new one.

I have 700 "items" and each item has three attributes- `a`, `b` and `e`. I loop through every item and use the three atrributes to calculate values for two "global" attributes called `c` and `d`.

I used two techniques to implement this:

1) Three 700-element arrays, one array for each of the three attributes:

```
 item0.a = array1[0]
 item0.b = array2[0]
 item0.e = array3[0]
```

2) One 2100-element array containing data for the three attributes consecutively:

```
 item0.a = array[offset + 0]
 item0.b = array[offset + 1]
 item0.e = array[offset + 2]
```

Now the three item attributes `a`, `b` and `e` are used together within the loop- therefore it would make sense that if you store them in one array the performance should be better than if you use the three-array technique.

This is because in technique #1 each of the three attributes (per same item) are located (700 x 4 bytes) apart. I would therefore have to retrieve three different cache lines for an item.

However, with technique #2 the three attributes are located adjacent in memory, so one cache line will give me all three item attributes. In fact because the cache line is 64 bytes and I am using integers- there will be 16 integers available per cache line load. This means I can process 16/3 = 5 items per cache line.

In other words, **technique #1 should require at least 3 cache line loads to process 5 items whereas technique #2 would only require one cache line load**. I was expecting technique #2 to be a lot faster.

Results (Win 7 64, MSVC 2012 with desktop Ivy Bridge CPU):

- Technique #1: 3000 CPU cycles (on average)
- Technique #2: 3400 CPU cycles (on average)

Technique #1 C++:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
double c = 0;
double d = 0;
bool data_for_all_items = true;
unsigned long long start = 0;
unsigned long long finish = 0;
unsigned int array1[700];
unsigned int array2[700];
unsigned int array3[700];

//I have left out code for simplicity. You can assume by now the arrays are populated.

start = __rdtscp(&x);

for(int i=0; i < 700; i++){
    unsigned int a= array1[i];     //Array 1
    unsigned int b= array2[i];     //Array 2

    data_for_all_items = data_for_all_items & (a!= -1 & b != -1);

    unsigned int e = array3[i];    //Array 3

    c += (a * e);
    d += (b * e);
}

finish = __rdtscp(&y);

if(data_for_all_items){
    std::cout << finish - start << std::endl;
    //This line prevents compiler over-optimizing
    std::cout << c << d << std::endl;
}
```

Assembly for Technique #1:

```
            unsigned int x;
            unsigned int y;

            start = __rdtscp(&x);
 rdtscp  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 lea         r8,[this]  

            for(int i=0; i < 700; i++){
 sub         rdi,rsi  
 or          rax,rdx  
 lea         r10,[rsi+4]  
 mov         ebx,46h  
 mov         dword ptr [r8],ecx  
 mov         r11,rax  
 sub         r9,rsi  
                unsigned int a = array1[i];
                unsigned int b = array2[i];

                all_instr_found = all_instr_found & (a != -1 & b != -1);
 cmp         dword ptr [r10-4],0FFFFFFFFh  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi-4],0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  

                unsigned int e = array3[i];
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9-4]  


                c += (a * e);
 mov         eax,ecx  
                d += (b * e);
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10-4]  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi-4]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [rdi+r10],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r9+r10]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [rdi+r10]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+4],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [rdi+r10+4],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r9+r10+4]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+4]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [rdi+r10+4]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+8],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [rdi+r10+8],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+8]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+8]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [rdi+r10+8]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+0Ch],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi+0Ch],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+0Ch]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
                d += (b * e);
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi+0Ch]  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+0Ch]  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+10h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi+10h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+10h]  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+10h]  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi+10h]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+14h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi+14h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+14h]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+14h]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi+14h]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+18h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi+18h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+18h]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+18h]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi+18h]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+1Ch],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi+1Ch],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+1Ch]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+1Ch]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi+1Ch]  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+20h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 setne       cl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10+rdi+20h],0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         bpl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10+r9+20h]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10+rdi+20h]  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10+20h]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 add         r10,28h  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 dec         rbx  
 jne         013FC6DA71h  

            }

            finish = __rdtscp(&y);
 rdtscp  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 lea         r8,[y]  
 or          rax,rdx  
 mov         dword ptr [r8],ecx
```

(It looks like the compiler was unrolling the loop five times for Technique #1)

Technique #2 C++:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
unsigned short pos = 0;
double c = 0;
double d = 0;
bool data_for_all_items = true;
unsigned long long start = 0;
unsigned long long finish = 0;
unsigned int array[2100];

//I have left out code for simplicity. You can assume by now the array is populated.

start = __rdtscp(&x);

while(pos < 2100){
    unsigned int a = array[pos + 0];     
    unsigned int b = array[pos + 1];     

    data_for_all_items = data_for_all_items & (a!= -1 & b != -1);

    unsigned int e = array[pos + 2];    

    c += (a * e);
    d += (b * e);
    pos = pos + 3;
}

finish = __rdtscp(&y);

if(data_for_all_items){
    std::cout << finish - start << std::endl;
    //This line prevents compiler over-optimizing
    std::cout << c << d << std::endl;
}
```

Assembly for Technique #2:

```
            start = __rdtscp(&x);
 rdtscp  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 lea         r9,[this]  
 mov         r11d,2BCh  
 or          rax,rdx  
 mov         dword ptr [r9],ecx  
 add         r10,8  
 mov         rbx,rax  
 nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  

            while(pos < 2100){

                unsigned int a = array[pos];
                unsigned int b = array[pos + 1];

                all_instr_found = all_instr_found & (a != -1 & b != -1);
 cmp         dword ptr [r10-4],0FFFFFFFFh  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 setne       dl  
 cmp         dword ptr [r10-8],0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       cl  

                unsigned int e = array[pos + 2];

                c += (a * e);
                d += (b * e);

                pos = pos + 3;
 add         r10,0Ch  
 and         dl,cl  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [r10-0Ch]  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 and         r15b,dl  
 imul        ecx,dword ptr [r10-10h]  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r10-14h]  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         eax,ecx  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 dec         r11  
 jne         013F21DA30h 
            }



            finish = __rdtscp(&y);
 rdtscp  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 lea         r8,[y]  
 or          rax,rdx  
 mov         dword ptr [r8],ecx
```

So no loop unrolling? This must be the reason right? Well I manually unrolled the loop using this C++:

```
    while(pos < 2100){
        unsigned int a1 = array[pos + 0];
        unsigned int b1 = array[pos + 1];
        unsigned int e1 = array[pos + 2];

        unsigned int a2 = array[pos + 3];
        unsigned int b2 = array[pos + 4];
        unsigned int e2 = array[pos + 5];

        unsigned int a3 = array[pos + 6];
        unsigned int b3 = array[pos + 7];
        unsigned int e3 = array[pos + 8];

        unsigned int a4 = array[pos + 9];
        unsigned int b4 = array[pos + 10];
        unsigned int e4 = array[pos + 11];

        unsigned int a5 = array[pos + 12];
        unsigned int b5 = array[pos + 13];
        unsigned int e5 = array[pos + 14];

        c += (a1 * e1) + (a2 * e2) + (a3 * e3) + (a4 * e4) + (a5 * e5);
        d += (b1 * e1) + (b2 * e2) + (b3 * e3) + (b4 * e4) + (b5 * e5);

        data_for_all_items = data_for_all_items & (a1 != -1 & b1 != -1) & (a2 != -1 & b2 != -1) & (a3 != -1 & b3 != -1) & (a4 != -1 & b4 != -1) & (a5 != -1 & b5 != -1);

        pos += 15;
    }

    if(data_for_all_items){
        std::cout << finish - start << std::endl;
        //This line prevents compiler over-optimizing
        std::cout << c << d << std::endl;
    }
```

generating this assembly:

```
           start = __rdtscp(&x);
 rdtscp  
 lea         r9,[x]  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+108h],8Ch  
 mov         dword ptr [r9],ecx  
 lea         r9,[r8+8]  
 or          rax,rdx  
 mov         qword ptr [y],r9  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax  
 nop  
                unsigned int a1 = array[pos + 0];
                unsigned int b1 = array[pos + 1];
                unsigned int e1 = array[pos + 2];
 mov         edi,dword ptr [r9]  

                unsigned int a2 = array[pos + 3];
 mov         r13d,dword ptr [r9+4]  
                unsigned int b2 = array[pos + 4];
 mov         r12d,dword ptr [r9+8]  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
                unsigned int e2 = array[pos + 5];
 mov         r10d,dword ptr [r9+0Ch]  

                unsigned int a3 = array[pos + 6];
 mov         r15d,dword ptr [r9+10h]  
                unsigned int b3 = array[pos + 7];
 mov         r14d,dword ptr [r9+14h]  
                unsigned int e3 = array[pos + 8];
 mov         r8d,dword ptr [r9+18h]  

                unsigned int a4 = array[pos + 9];
 mov         ebp,dword ptr [r9+1Ch]  
                unsigned int b4 = array[pos + 10];
 mov         esi,dword ptr [r9+20h]  
                unsigned int e4 = array[pos + 11];
 mov         edx,dword ptr [r9+24h]  

                unsigned int a5 = array[pos + 12];
 mov         ebx,dword ptr [r9+28h]  
                unsigned int b5 = array[pos + 13];
 mov         r11d,dword ptr [r9+2Ch]  
                unsigned int e5 = array[pos + 14];
 mov         r9d,dword ptr [r9+30h]  

                c += (a1 * e1) + (a2 * e2) + (a3 * e3) + (a4 * e4) + (a5 * e5);
 mov         eax,edx  
 mov         dword ptr [x],r13d  
                d += (b1 * e1) + (b2 * e2) + (b3 * e3) + (b4 * e4) + (b5 * e5);
 imul        edx,esi  
 imul        eax,ebp  
 mov         ecx,r9d  
 imul        r9d,r11d  
 imul        ecx,ebx  
 add         r9d,edx  
 add         ecx,eax  
 mov         eax,r8d  
 imul        r8d,r14d  
 imul        eax,r15d  
 add         r9d,r8d  

                all_instr_found = all_instr_found & (a1 != -1 & b1 != -1) & (a2 != -1 & b2 != -1) & (a3 != -1 & b3 != -1) & (a4 != -1 & b4 != -1) & (a5 != -1 & b5 != -1);
 movzx       r8d,byte ptr [this]  
 add         ecx,eax  
 mov         eax,r10d  
 imul        r10d,r12d  
 add         r9d,r10d  
 imul        eax,r13d  
 mov         r13,qword ptr [y]  
 add         ecx,eax  
 mov         eax,edi  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [r13-8]  
 add         eax,ecx  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 mov         rax,r13  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [rax-4]  
 imul        edi,edx  
 cmp         r11d,0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm6,xmm0  
 setne       cl  

                all_instr_found = all_instr_found & (a1 != -1 & b1 != -1) & (a2 != -1 & b2 != -1) & (a3 != -1 & b3 != -1) & (a4 != -1 & b4 != -1) & (a5 != -1 & b5 != -1);
 cmp         ebx,0FFFFFFFFh  
 lea         eax,[rdi+r9]  
 mov         r9,r13  
 xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
 cvtsi2sd    xmm0,rax  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         esi,0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         ebp,0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         r14d,0FFFFFFFFh  
 addsd       xmm7,xmm0  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         r15d,0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         r12d,0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         dword ptr [x],0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         edx,0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 cmp         dword ptr [r13-8],0FFFFFFFFh  
 setne       al  
 and         cl,al  
 and         r8b,cl  

                pos += 15;
 add         r9,3Ch  
 mov         qword ptr [y],r9  
 mov         byte ptr [this],r8b  


            while(pos < 2100){
 dec         qword ptr [rsp+108h]  
 jne         013F31DA50h  
            }


            finish = __rdtscp(&y);
 rdtscp  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 lea         r9,[y]  
 mov         dword ptr [r9],ecx  
 mov         r15,qword ptr [rsp+0A8h]  
 mov         r13,qword ptr [rsp+0B0h]  
 mov         r12,qword ptr [rsp+0B8h]  
 or          rax,rdx
```

The new manual loop-unrolling takes 3500 CPU cycles on average, slower than the un-rolled original version which was 3400 CPU cycles.

Can somebody please explain why code which should fetch from the cache 3x less is slower and whether there is a way to help the compiler or get this code faster than technique #1?

Comment: Chances are that, no matter which version, all of your array(s) are still in the cache when that computational loop executes. IMHO, trying to program so that cache hits are minimzed is (pardon the harsh word) nonsense. Write clean, maintainable code and let Intel's engineers worry about the hardware, and expect gcc maintainers to provide good optimization.

Comment: @laune no disrespect but the reason I am posting it is to learn more about performance and why understand why the theory is not holding up.  I chose C++ because I wanted to understand what is happening "under the hood".

Comment: "Technique #1 should require at least 3 cache line loads to process 5 items whereas technique #2 would only require one cache line load": Perhaps, but I think you're forgetting that with technique #1, there are now 3 cache lines filled, meaning that 16 items can be processed without refetching.

Comment: @Cornstalks ok but less cache lines need to be fetched? Technique #2 still has all the data in one cache line which cannot be slower than 3 cache lines, surely?

Comment: @user997112: Why can't 1 cache line be slower than 3 cache lines? You can put 64 bytes in one cache line, or 192 bytes in three cache lines. If you use 3 cache lines, you don't have to refill the cache lines as often, but if you use 1 cache line you have to refill it three times more often.

Comment: did you try vectorizing the code using SIMD? It may improve speed even further

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc thats what I am going to do next :)

Comment: Can't believe when I compile this with ICC 14 its 25% slower than MSVC. I would have thought this was the type of code the ICC would optimize the hell out of......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some prefetching in #2, and you might just reach that lofty performance goal.
For gcc, use inline assembler and the 3dNow Prefetch instructions (just about all left from that extension nowadays).

Your example number one probably runs faster because doing 3 independent memory requests (due to out-of-order-execution) means better throughput on the memory bus (less idle time).

That's a nice example for micro-optimisation not only making things harder on you, but being self-defeating.
The processor designer and maker as well as the compiler writers spend really amazing amounts of money, time and talent optimizing for the common case so second-guessing them is hard.

Comment: I'm not using GCC, but would you be able to show me how you would do the prefetching in GCC within your answer?

Comment: Did you already read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: I have seen that article before- but I don't see what branch prediction has to do with this?

Comment: @user997112: Just thought that was a low-level post you really should read too due to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some naive back-of-the-envelope arithmetic.

Fetching from an int array abc[3N] in a loop will require (3N*4+63)/64 cache fetches. After processing processing 5.33 triplets (5*4*3 = 60) you'll need the next cache line.

Fetching from three discontinuous arrays requires 3 fetches for the first iteration, but then these three cache lines can stay in memory for the next 15 iterations (64/4 = 16). So you'll need 3*((N*4+63)/64) fetches.

Using 700 for N:

```
F1 = (8400+63)/64 = 132
F2 = 3*((700*4+63)/64) = 132
```

Given the cache sizes of the CPUs there's no chance that lines are thrown out while the iteration proceeds on three arrays in parallel.

Comment: So they should take same time roughly?

Comment: As far as access to the arrays is concerned, yes. The loop code appears to vary, which can explain the moderate difference you have observed.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Ivy Brige CPUs can predict-fetch multiple cache lines, and as long as the prediction guesses right, you'd not notice any difference between a single stream of data and up to ~6 streams of data (the exact number of streams depends on CPU design).

Most likely the differences you see have more to do with the change in assembly output than L-cache behavior.  The asm generated is clearly very different in each case, with the last version (your hand-unrolled one) having the most instructions per iteration - a pretty safe indication that it should be slower simply for forcing more "real work" through the CPU's instruction decoder and execution units.

Moreover, `cvtsi2sd` in particular is a slow instruction on Ivy Bridge, and could skew your benchmark result simply depending on where in the instruction stream it's placed in relation to the input (a dependency) and the output (the result latency).  If you want to isolate your test to measure memory performance alone. I would strongly recommend eliminating that instruction from the benchmark.